# Socket recv() bug in python3.7

Tags: python, sockets, send, recv

Client:

```
#The program should send two strings and the server should return the interclassed string back

import socket
import time
import sys


HEADERSIZE=10
firstString = input("First string: ")
secondString = input("Second string: ")
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8888
firstString = f'{len(firstString):<{HEADERSIZE}}'+firstString
secondString = f'{len(secondString):<{HEADERSIZE}}'+secondString

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(bytes(firstString, 'utf-8'))
s.send(bytes(secondString, 'utf-8'))
fullMsg=''
while 1:
    msg = s.recv(8)
    if len(msg)<=0:
        break
    fullMsg += msg.decode('utf-8')
print(fullMsg)
s.close()
```

Server:

```
#trebuie trimisa si dimensiunea
import socket


def interclass(firstString , secondString):
    i =0 
    j =0
    interString=''
    while i < len(firstString) and j < len(secondString):
        if firstString[i] < secondString[j]:
            interString+=firstString[i]
            i=i+1
        else: 
            interString+=secondString[j]
            j=j+1
    while i < len(firstString):
        interString += firstString[i]
        i=i+1
    while j < len(secondString):
        interString+=secondString[j]
        j=j+1
    return interString

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8888;
HEADERSIZE=10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    messages=[]
    newMsg = True
    fullMsg = ''
    msgLength = -1
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv(16)
        if len(msg)<=0:
            break
        msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
        fullMsg += msg
        if len(fullMsg)>=HEADERSIZE and newMsg == True:
            newMsg = False
            msgLength = int(fullMsg[:HEADERSIZE-1])
            fullMsg = fullMsg[HEADERSIZE:HEADERSIZE+1+msgLength]
        if not newMsg and len(fullMsg)>=msgLength:
            messages.append(fullMsg[:msgLength])
            fullMsg = fullMsg[msgLength:]
            newMsg = True
    interString = interclass(messages[0], messages[1])
    conn.sendall(bytes(interString,'utf-8'))
conn.close()
```

The application works until I try the part where I try to send data from the server. It all blocks at the recv() command in the client. I searched all the internet for a solution and I tried making it a non-blocked socket and deal with exception... Still not working. I would appreciate some help. Thanks!!

Comment: Your server is blocking at `conn.recv(16)` waiting for more input. You can, I think, make this example work by explicitly shutting down the write side of the socket in the client after the last message is sent with `s.shutdown(socket. SHUT_WR)`, but for even a slightly more complicated example you'll need to implement your own protocol on top of TCP. And no, there's no bug in `recv()` demonstrated here.

Comment: The server doesn't get blocked. The client does. Like I said, all works until i try to send anything from server. Is at the client msg.recv() where it stucks. And, yes, I expressed wrong maybe. Thank you, anyway!! =)

Comment: The client blocks on receive because the server hasn't sent any data. The server hasn't sent any data because it is blocking where I said it was.

Comment: And why the server doesn't block at the conn.recv() until I place a recv() in the client? This is what I need to find out.

Comment: Why do you believe the server will ever exit the while loop? What condition would cause `conn.recv(16)` to return a zero-length `msg`?

Comment: Simply because I deleted the recv() from client and the server always exits.

Comment: Yes, because without recv() the client simply closes the socket. That will cause recv() in the server to return a zero-length message and will exit the loop. Perhaps you can simply try my suggestion of placing `s.shutdown(socket. SHUT_WR)` in the client immediately after the second `send()`.

Comment: Doesn't fix it.. =(

Comment: Yes, it does. I have finally run your code and it behaves exactly as I explained.